# Multiple markers at this line in dice code (Eclipse)

Tags: java

I writing this code in Eclipse but it tells me that it has multiple markers at 2 lines. I've tried to solve the problem, but more markers occur. The errors that occur are at line 15 and 18

```
public class Cup {
    private Dice d1 = new Dice();
    private Dice d2 = new Dice();

    public void roll(){
        d1.roll();
        d2.roll();
    }

    public int getvalue1(){
        return d1.getValue();
    }
    public int getvalue2(){
        return d2.getValue();
    }
    public int getSum(){
        return d1.getValue() + d2.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which lines are 15 and 18?

Comment: What are the exact marker messages?

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Duplicate local variable $missing$
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - The method getSum() is undefined for the type Cup
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
 - Illegal modifier for parameter $missing$; only final is permitted
 - Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete 
  LocalVariableDeclaration

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Illegal modifier for parameter $missing$; only final is permitted
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
 - Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete 
  LocalVariableDeclaration
 - The method getvalue2() is undefined for the type Cup

Answer (score 1):

Could be a copy/paste error, but you seem to be missing a `}` at the end of the `getvalue1()` method, and have an extra one at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Till you don't show the whole code I cannot guarantee what is wrong. Changing you code to this might help. Share the code for Dice too.

```
public class Cup {
    private Dice d1 = new Dice();
    private Dice d2 = new Dice();

    public void roll(){
        d1.roll();
        d2.roll();
    }

    public int getvalue1(){
        return d1.getValue();
    }
    public int getvalue2(){
        return d2.getValue();
    }
    public int getSum(){
        return (getValue1() + getValue2());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've solved the problem :) The problem was that I was missin a } at the end of the getvalue1() method, and had an extra one at the end.

Comment: @user4118143 please write a new answer or mark one of the answer that helped you as correct. It might help the next person.